# JavaScript callBack Gets Ran Twice - Should Only Run Once?

Tags: javascript

I would like to clarify first that I have searched for a solution to my answer for well over 2 hours and cannot seem to locate a solution.

I have a function `addProductCheck();`

This function is called on item click and seems to working with no difficulty. The problem arises when the next function with a callback is ran.

```
cartProductExists(objectVars, function(cartItem) {

}
```

This is designed to run a Asynchronous call to my database, check for the item inside the cart table, and then return the callback with the results for further manipulation.

```
cartProductExists(objectVars, function(cartItem) {

    if (cartItem != null) {
    //Ran after callback returns as cartItem is no longer null
    }else{
    //Gets ran the first time cartProductsExists is called, when it shouldn't.
    }

}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this, as to my knowledge the rest of the code inside the callback shouldn't even be getting ran until the callback triggers a response.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code where `cartProductExists` is called?

Comment: did you try setting a break point in the debugger and figure out what exactly is being triggered twice? My guess is you invoke `cartProductExists` twice for some reason, but its impossible to tell given the information you shared. If you could share a jsFIddle, it would be better.

Comment: You need to post the code for the `addProductCheck` function too. I highly suspect that you need to add `preventDefault` to your event handler, but cannot be sure until I see the code.

Comment: I apologize for taking your time. I just posted my answer.  It explains my noobie mistake which I am sure others are making. Your time is still appreciated my friends.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that inside my `cartProductExists()` function, I needed to place a `callBack()` at the last line, just because my query would only callback in the case of finding the object I was looking for. I was thinking that having one at the end would return a null callback to continue the process.

What was apparently happening is that while my asynchronous event was waiting, it was still proceeding to the end of my code and triggering the second `callBack()`, but before my async task was complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cartItem == null || cartItem == "") {
    //Ran after callback returns as cartItem is no longer null
} else {
    //Gets ran the first time cartProductsExists is called, when it shouldn't.
}
```

can you try in that way?